# Getting information about multiple URLs in one request from Facebook, Twitter, Google+, and LinkedIn

Tags: facebook, api, twitter, linkedin-api

With Facebook, you can do this:

```
http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=SELECT total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://stackoverflow.com OR url="http://stackexchange.com" OR url="http://example.com"
```

However, with Twitter, Google, and LinkedIn, I can only figure out how to get information about one URL at a time. Here are the URLs (took me a while to find):

```
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://example.com

https://clients6.google.com/rpc (Google uses a POST request)

http://www.linkedin.com/cws/share-count?url=http://example.com
```

How can I get information about multiple URLs in one request from Twitter, Google+, and LinkedIn

Comment: How can I get information about multiple URLs in one request from Twitter, Google+, and LinkedIn

Comment: You should edit your post to contain that question - it is not too clear from your post what you are asking.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

One HTTP request is directed at only 1 url.  How else would an HTTP request get routed to the correct place if it couldn't figure out the IP address of where to send the request?

You do have a solution.  Write a web service on your server such as `http://www.example.com/ajax/GetAllAtOnce.asmx`.  In your server-side code, you create four web requests, gather back the information and send it back to the client.

Comment: How is this answer correct? The question was about getting information from an API about multiple URLs, e.g. I want to know how many tweets reddit.com or stack overflow.com have on twitter, so the url in this case is a parameter to such an API. The question was not about sending a single request to all APIs, it was about sending multiple URL parameters to one of them (e.g. twitter)

Comment: You still would have to design around the lowest common denominator from each of the APIs.  So if one of them don't support passing in multiple urls, then u would need to make multiple request to that server and "concat" together the responses.